# Is there benefit of MLNX OFED install vs default Redhat InfiniBand Support

Tags: rhel, infiniband

When using RHEL 8.8, there is a choice to be made for users with Mellanox InfiniBand hardware. They can either utilize Red Hat's included `InfiniBand Support` group installation (which I choose to do during the installation process) in order to enable InfiniBand networking, or they can opt for `MLNX_OFED_LINUX-23.04-1.1.3.0-rhel8.8-x86_64.iso` and execute their `mlnxofedinstall` script, which replaces Red Hat packages with their own.

Aside from firmware updates, does anyone know of any advantages of using the MLNX path as opposed to the Red Hat path for setting up InfiniBand?

The MLNX approach generally involves more setup and configuration, so I am interested in any performance justifications for using the MLNX method (considering that I am using their hardware) instead of what Red Hat provides.

For reference:

```
Usage: ./mlnxofedinstall [OPTIONS]

Installation control:
    --force              Force installation
    --tmpdir             Change tmp directory. Default: /tmp
    -k|--kernel <version>
                         Default on this system: 3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64
    -s|--kernel-sources <path>
                         Default on this system: /lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64/build
    -U|--update          Update installed version
    --with-32bit         Install 32-bit libraries. Relevant for x86_64 platforms
    --without-32bit      Skip 32-bit libraries installation (Default). Relevant for x86_64 platforms
    --distro             Set Distro name for the running OS (e.g: rhel6.5, sles12sp3). Default: Use auto-detection
    --skip-distro-check  Do not check MLNX_OFED_LINUX vs Distro matching
    --without-depcheck   Run the installation without verifying that all required Distro's packages are installed
    --check-deps-only    Check for missing required Distro's packages and exit
    --print-distro       Print distribution name and exit

    --add-kernel-support
                         Add kernel support (Run mlnx_add_kernel_support.sh) and install it
    --add-kernel-support-build-only
                         Add kernel support (Run mlnx_add_kernel_support.sh) and exit

    --kernel-extra-args '<args>'
                         pass <args> to kernel configure script (single paraeter, space separated)
                         - Pass it along with --add-kernel-support

    --kmp                Install kernel RPMs with KMP support if available
                         - Enabled by default with official MLNX_OFED_LINUX releases
                         - Disabled by default if new MLNX_OFED_LINUX was created with mlnx_add_kernel_support.sh
                         - Passing it along with --add-kernel-support will pass --kmp to mlnx_add_kernel_support.sh
    --disable-kmp        Install kernel RPMs without KMP support if available
                         - Enabled by default if new MLNX_OFED_LINUX was created with mlnx_add_kernel_support.sh
    --skip-kmp-verify    Do not check if the KMP rpms are compatiable with the target kernel
    --speed-up-kmp       Speed up KMP RPMs installation by skipping %post section and running the required operations once for all KMPs

    --umad-dev-rw        Grant non root users read/write permission for umad devices instead of default
    --umad-dev-na        Prevent from non root users read/write access for umad devices. Overrides '--umad-dev-rw'
    --enable-mlnx_tune   Enable Running the mlnx_tune utility
    --enable-affinity    Run mlnx_affinity script upon boot
    --disable-affinity   Disable mlnx_affinity script (Default)
    --skip-unsupported-devices-check
                         Don't abort if system has an older, unsupported card
    --enable-opensm      Run opensm upon boot

    --package-install-options
                         RPM install options to use when installing RPM packages (comma separated list)
    --pre-install-<package> <path to script>
                         Run given script before given package's install
    --post-install-<package> <path to script>
                         Run given script after given package's install

Firmware update control:
    --without-fw-update  Skip firmware update
    --fw-update-only     Update firmware. Skip driver installation
    --force-fw-update    Force firmware update
    --fw-image-dir       Firmware images directory to use instead of default package content

Package selection:
    -c|--config <packages config_file>
                         Example of the config file can be found under docs
    --all                Install all available packages
    --bluefield          Install BlueField packages
    --hpc                Install minimum packages required for HPC
    --basic              Install minimum packages for basic functionality
    --dpdk               Install minimum packages required for DPDK
    --ovs-dpdk           Install DPDK and OVS packages
    --vma                Install minimum packages required for VMA
    --xlio                Install minimum packages required for XLIO
    --guest              Install minimum packages required by guest OS
    --hypervisor         Install minimum packages required by hypervisor OS
    --with-fabric-collector
                         Enable installing fabric-collector package
    --with-nvmf          Enable NVMEoF support
    --with-nfsrdma       Enable NFSoRDMA support
    --without-nfsrdma    Disable NFSoRDMA support (Default)

Extra package filtering:
    --kernel-only        Install kernel space packages only
    --user-space-only    Filter selected packages and install only User Space packages
    --without-<package>  Do not install package
    --with-<package>     Force installing package

Miscellaneous:
    -h|--help            Display this help message and exit
    --post-start-delay <sec>
                         Set openibd POST_START_DELAY parameter in seconds. (Default 0)
    -p|--print-available Print available packages for current platform
                         And create corresponding ofed.conf file
    --copy-ifnames-udev  Copy compatibility udev rules for interface names

Output control:
    -v|-vv|-vvv          Set verbosity level
    -q                   Set quiet - no messages will be printed
```

Answer (score 1):

The Red Hat distributed version is generally lagging behind the Mellanox/NVIDIA release and does not include all the utilities of the Mellanox/NVIDIA version. I remove the Red Hat version if it is installed and install the Mellanox/NVIDIA version.

I started doing this back on Red Hat 7 when the version that Red Hat shipped had a bug. This bug caused it to only work with Reliable Connections (RC).

It would encounter errors when trying to run the code using Unreliable Connections (UC) or Unreliable Datagrams (UD).

The other aspect is that the firmware and the version of the code have interdependencies. You need to ensure that the firmware you have is included in the supported list for the version of OFED.